# Configure Nginx for Listening Multiple Ports

Tags: nginx

I am trying to create multiple applications that listen different ports on one server with one IP address (without domain name, subdomain).

Application A listens port 80
Application B listens port 8080

And I want to access two applications separately through
 
`http//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80` and `http//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080`

If I have domain name I can create multiple subdomain, and configure nginx like:

```
server {
    server_name A.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    root someplace/;
    try_files /maintenance.html $uri $uri.html @puma;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;               
        proxy_pass http//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
    }
}

server {
    server_name B.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    root someplace/;
    try_files /maintenance.html $uri $uri.html @puma;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;               
        proxy_pass http//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080;
    }
}
```

What if I don't have a domain name, is that possible to access through
 
`http//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80` and `http//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080`

Something like this?

```
server {
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    listen 80;
    root someplace/;
    try_files /maintenance.html $uri $uri.html @puma;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;               
        proxy_pass http//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
    }
}
server {
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    listen 8080;
    root someplace/;
    try_files /maintenance.html $uri $uri.html @puma;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;               
        proxy_pass http//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems, you already have a solution. Is there something in your config that does not work as you want?

Comment: you should also be able to use `listen 80; listen 8080;` in the same serveroption

Comment: just add multiple port string for the same server if needed